# Boolean Simplification: AB + BC + A'C

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Last time I mistyped the equation.

I have this logic equation: AB + BC + A'C

I know that the simplified equation is AB + A'C, but I don't know the steps to get there. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\rm AB+BC+A'C \\= AB+(A+A')BC+A'C$